# "Root element is missing" error but I have a root element

Tags: c#, xml

If anyone can explain why I'm getting a "Root element is missing" error when my XML document (image attached) has a root element, they win a pony which fires lazers from its eyes.

[image]

Code:

```
if (ISF.FileExists("Players.xml"))
{
    string xml;
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream rawStream = ISF.OpenFile("Players.xml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(rawStream);
        xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
          XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings { IgnoreComments = true, IgnoreWhitespace = true };
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings);
         while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            switch (xmlReader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    switch (xmlReader.Name)
                    {
                        case "numberOfPlayers":
                            string nodeValue = xmlReader.ReadContentAsString();
                            int NODEVALUE = int.Parse(nodeValue);
                            MessageBox.Show(" " + NODEVALUE);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: any particular reason you are using `XmlReader` here?

Comment: Im totally new to reading XML in C#... that's probably the reason I'm using XmlReader. I don't quite understand what mtahmed means?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Your problem is due to this line:

```
xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

This positions the reader stream to the end so that when `XmlReader.Create` is executed, there is nothing left in the stream for it to read.

If you need the `xml` string to be populated, then you need to close and reopen the reader prior to `XmlReader.Create`. Otherwise, removing or commenting this line out will solve your problem.

Comment: @DanTonyBrown: Glad I could help. Remember to click the checkmark and up arrow next to any answer that solves or helps you solve your problem so that future visitors to the question will know that this worked for you.

Comment: If I knew XML better, maybe *I'd* be the one getting a pony that fired lasers ;)

Comment: @competent_tech i need to wait for the time limit to expire to mark you as the correct answer :)

Comment: And you can send my pony to any needy child that is intent on world domination.

Comment: Durp, that's what I did: I had previously added debug code to read the OuterXml so I could see what its value was, forgot about it, and didn't realize that was repositioning the reader when I came back to the project later after being distracted with something else.

Answer (score 4):

Reset the base stream's position each time it is read if you want to read from the beginning as stated earlier, but you **don't** have to re-create the stream each time.

```
String xmlResource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".XML.IODeleter.xsd";
configXsd = new StreamReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(xmlResource));
if (configXsd != null)
  {
    configXsd.BaseStream.Position = 0;

    File.WriteAllText(apppath + @"\" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".XML.IODeleter.xsd", configXsd.ReadToEnd());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a quick little function to reference before each new XmlReader...

```
private void ResetStream()
{
    /*
    The point of this is simply to open the stream with a StreamReader object
    and set the position of the stream to the beginning again.
    */

     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(m_stream);

     if (reader != null)
    {
        reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
    }
}
```

So when I'm working in xml I call it right before I create my reader.  I always have the same stream in memory and never recreate that.

```
ResetStream();
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(m_stream)) { reader.Read(); }
```