# "Root element is missing" exception given when trying to parse XML file

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, ksoap2

I'm trying to set up parsing for a test XML generated with ksoap2 in Android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header />
    <v:Body>
        <v:SOAPBODY>
            <v:INFO i:type="v:INFO">
                <v:LAITETUNNUS i:type="d:string">EI_TUNNUSTA</v:LAITETUNNUS>
            </v:INFO>
            <v:TOIMINNOT i:type="v:TOIMINNOT">
                <v:TOIMINTA i:type="d:string">ASETUKSET_HAKU</v:TOIMINTA>
            </v:TOIMINNOT>
            <v:SISALTO i:type="v:SISALTO">
                <v:KUVA i:type="d:string">AGFAFDGFDGFG</v:KUVA>
                <v:MITTAUS i:type="d:string">12,42,12,4,53,12</v:MITTAUS>
            </v:SISALTO>
        </v:SOAPBODY>
    </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

But seemingly i can't parse it in any way. The exception is always that "Root element is not found" even when it goes through XML-validators like the one at w3schools. If i'm correct the contents of the body shouldn't be an issue when the problem is with root element.

The test code for parsing i try to use in C# is:

```
            using (StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(Context.Request.InputStream))
            {
                try
                {
                    XDocument xmlInput = new XDocument();
                    streamreader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                    string tmp = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
                    var xmlreader = XmlReader.Create(streamreader.BaseStream);
                    xmlInput = XDocument.Parse(tmp);
                    xmlInput = XDocument.Load(xmlreader);
                catch (Exception e)
                { }
```

where the `xmlInput = XDocument.Parse(tmp);` does indeed parse it to a `XDocument`, not a navigable one, though. Then `xmlInput = XDocument.Load(xmlreader);` throws the exception for not having a root element. I'm completely at loss here because i managed to parse and navigate the almost same xml with `XMLDocument` and `XDocument` classes before, and i fear i made some changes i didn't notice.

Thanks in advance.

Update: Here's the string tmp as requested :

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><v:Envelope xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:d=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:c=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:v=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><v:Header /><v:Body><v:SOAPBODY><v:INFO i:type=\"v:INFO\"><v:LAITETUNNUS i:type=\"d:string\">EI_TUNNUSTA</v:LAITETUNNUS></v:INFO><v:TOIMINNOT i:type=\"v:TOIMINNOT\"><v:TOIMINTA i:type=\"d:string\">ASETUKSET_HAKU</v:TOIMINTA></v:TOIMINNOT><v:SISALTO i:type=\"v:SISALTO\"><v:KUVA i:type=\"d:string\">AGFAFDGFDGFG</v:KUVA><v:MITTAUS i:type=\"d:string\">12,42,12,4,53,12</v:MITTAUS></v:SISALTO></v:SOAPBODY></v:Body></v:Envelope>\r\n"
```

Update: Even with `XDocument.Load(new StreamReader(Context.Request.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8)); the parsing will fail.`

Comment: I think `StreamReader` is not required here. Just use `XDocument`

Comment: Parsing the xml directly works fine for me (.Net 4.5). Could it be that the stream is read with the wrong encoding? Can you paste the value of `tmp` after you read the stream?

Comment: You sample is .... strange. Network streams are usually not seek-able... reading stream twice (`ReadToEnd` and `XmlReader.Create`) does not make much sense... Are you sure it is the code you have problem with or you just pasted multiple attempts to parse together in random order?

Comment: I think it's what Alexei said. If you use `XDocument.Load(Context.Request.InputStream);` without first reading the stream into a string - does the error still occurs?

Comment: Added the temp string contents. And yes the code may seem stupid because it has lines i've used for debugging and trying to figure out this. I've tried also

XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(Context.Request.InputStream);
XDocument xmlinput = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);

But it still fails in parsing.

Comment: `XDocument.Load` uses `XmlReader.Create` even when you're not using it explicitly, so `XmlReader` seems like the source of the problem... What if you use `XDocument.Load(new StreamReader(Context.Request.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8))` ?

Comment: Shlomi. With your exact code and no any sort of reading of the stream before, the root element is still missing.

Comment: @newa :( Well, it sounds like a bug... Work around it -> what's the problem with working `XDocument.Parse(tmp)` (what's "not a navigable" means?)? I would also try to play with the xml and see if it works (like removing the xml declaration, eg: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` or putting the whole xml (without the declaration) inside an element (eg: `<root><v.Envelope ...>...</v.Envelope></root>`). It's ugly... but working ugly is better than not working at all. Sorry for not being able to provide more help.

Comment: Oh and sorry about not answering about what "not navigable" means. It's that it can't parse the document in a meaningful way. While debugging the xdocument-object i did eventually find the tags and the texts inside them, but it was so deep inside (some 15+ steps from root and not in the place where they should have been) the structure i couldn't imagine anyone writing a code for it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've read to the end of the stream once already, you need to reset the position in the stream again.  see: ["Root element is missing" error but I have a root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453987/root-element-is-missing-error-but-i-have-a-root-element)