# Root element is missing using Xdocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, httpresponse

Using the below code i get "Root element is missing." on certain requests sent but using the exact same data criteria:

```
    HttpWebRequest WebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
    HttpWebResponse WebResponse = null;
    Encoding ResponseEncoding = null;
    StreamReader ResponseReader = null;
    XNamespace ns = "http://example.com/ns";
    XDocument XDoc = null;

    WebRequest.Method = RequestedMethod(ref MethodType);
    WebRequest.ContentType = Contenttype;
    WebRequest.KeepAlive = true;

    try
    {
        WebResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)WebRequest.GetResponse();
        if (WebResponse != null)
        {
            ResponseEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            m_ResponseStream = WebResponse.GetResponseStream();
            ResponseReader = new StreamReader(m_ResponseStream, ResponseEncoding);
            XDoc = XDocument.Parse(ResponseReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Catch Exception

    }
    finally
    {
        if (ResponseReader != null)
        {
            ResponseReader.Close();
            ResponseReader.Dispose();
        }

        if (WebResponse != null)
        {
            WebResponse.Close();
        }
    }
```

I have debugged this code but each time i debug it, it always returns the correct data. If i run the application in a normal manner the again same data requests shows the error message every so often. The idea is to read the Response into XDoc and the use Xdoc to iterate through the nodes and do whatever operation required.

I've checked the internet for solutions but i think ive covered everything i can think of but i dont know why the error pops up on some occassions but never in debug mode. Any thoughts? I have seen this link which i *think* i have the essentials covered ["Root element is missing" error but I have a root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453987/root-element-is-missing-error-but-i-have-a-root-element)

Comment: Try logging your input/output everytime. Even though you may think everything is same, it may not be.

Comment: I tried the above and over a week's monitoring i noticed the error "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.". Now i believe i can trap this is a try catch block and take appropriate actions, however first call would be if the code above has any issues? If not the i will mark your comment as an answer.

Comment: The code above looks sane. If you have collected any sort of logs, then one other thing you can try is create a unit test, and using the real world inputs that **failed**, run the unit test to see if there is anything subtle that you missed. You cannot mark the comment as an answer, I'll have to give it as an answer. :)